# Selenium C# InPrivate Mode Internet Explorer IE 11 throws exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I have a requirement to open IE11 in private-mode on Winodws10. Tried by following code but it is throwing exception "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Unable to use CreateProcess() API. To use CreateProcess() with Internet Explorer 8 or higher, the value of registry setting in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth must be '0'."

Code:
 int val = Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth", "", -1));

```
            InternetExplorerOptions ops = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            ops.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
            ops.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
            IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(url, ops);
```

There is key in RegEdit and i can read successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Removing `ops.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;` helps to start the browser, but NOT in private mode. You need the combination of

```
ops.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
ops.BrowserCommandLineArguments = "-private";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just like yours. I searched a lot and found no solution until I tried to delete the following line:

```
ops.ForceCreateProcessApi = true;
```

And thank God, the problem was solved. I'd love to know if it helped you solve the problem